# $R$ be an infinite Boolean ring ($a^2=a,\forall a \in R$) with unity , then must $R$ be uncountable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, ring-theory

Let $R$ be an infinite Boolean ring ($a^2=a,\forall a \in R$) with unity , then is it true that $R$ must be uncountable ?

Comment: What do you think? Are you wanting to verify the claim? Are you doubting the truth of the claim, and if so, why the doubts?  (I'm assuming you've already learned we all appreciate some context.)  Did you find the statement in an exercise, which asks you to mark as true or false? Please edit your question with more context, and an explanation why you might believe the statement and/or why you might be  in doubt.

Comment: @amWhy : I recently did an exercise in measure theory which states that any infinite $\sigma$-algebra must be uncountable ... therefrom arises the question ...

Comment: That helps; just curious what leads you to question its veracity.  Nothing wrong with that!  It just helps us to help if we have a better idea what your reservations are, rightly or mistakenly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, an infinite Boolean ring with unity need not be uncountable.

The Löwenheim-Skolem theorem says that any first-order theory with an infinite model has models of all infinite cardinalities.

The notion of Boolean ring with unity is axiomatizable in first-order logic, and that first-order theory has infinite models (any power set of an infinite set, under symmetric difference and intersection).  So it has a countably infinite model.

I think this is a specific example: the collection of all sets of integers which are either finite or have finite complement, under symmetric difference and intersection.

Comment: You've beat me to the punch!

Comment: @Mitchell Spector : I really don't have the capacity currently to understand what all you have written ... just to make sure I am assuming choice ... so is it still possible to have countably infinite Boolean ring with unity ?

Comment: @user228169: While the axiom of choice is necessary for proving the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem, it isn't *really* needed in showing that the finite/co-finite sets of integers make a countably infinite Boolean ring.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : Sorry if I am being silly but what I meant to ask is that is it consistent with choice that countably infinite boolean ring with unity exists ?

Comment: Yes, just take $\lbrace X \subseteq \mathbb{N} \mid X \text{ is finite  or }\mathbb{N}\setminus X \text{ is finite}\rbrace,$ under symmetric difference and intersection.  (Löwenheim-Skolem needs choice in general, but not for this specific example.)

Comment: @user228169: And I wrote that choice has *absolutely nothing* to do with the fact. So yes.

Comment: Mitchell, in fact this specific example is a direct construction, and it does not even appealing to the LS theorem.

Comment: @Mitchell Spector : Isn't your example a $\sigma$-algebra ? then if it is infinite , I can prove it must be uncountable ... see my comment at the question ... any infinite $\sigma$-algebra must be uncountable ...

Comment: @AsafKaragila, that's true, and maybe I shouldn't even have brought in Löwenheim-Skolem.  But that's how I knew that there was a countably infinite Boolean ring with unity before even finding the specific example, and I thought it would be instructive to mention that.

Comment: I agree, that was my initial instinct too.

Comment: @user228169 No, it's not a $\sigma$-algebra; it's not closed under countably infinite unions or intersections.

Comment: @user228169 No, it's countable.  The set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is countable.  It's in 1-1 correspondence with the set of all cofinite subsets of $\mathbb{N},$ so that set is also countable.  And therefore the union of those two sets is countable.

Comment: @MitchellSpector : Oh sorry ... its just an algebra ...

Answer (score 1):

An elementary example is not hard.

If $F_2$ is the ring with two elements, take the subalgebra of $\prod_{i=0}^\infty F_2$ generated by $\oplus_{i=0}^\infty F_2$ and the identity of the product ring.

There are obviously only countably many sequences of finite support in $\oplus_{i=0}^\infty F_2$, and the subalgebra generated is literally $\oplus_{i=0}^\infty F_2\cup \{1+x\mid x\in \oplus_{i=0}^\infty F_2\}$, so the whole thing is countable.

---

Later:

Just noticed the ring of sets described at the end of the other post. This ring is isomorphic to that one.